# Scrollbar not works in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10

```
Issue rises only in IE 10 it works fine on IE 8, IE 9 and chrome.
I have table with 2 “tr” tags
The first “tr” tag has div with css class “scrollTV” contains tree nodes
```

When I add height: 100%; to that class and I expanded the tree nodes it expands and push the second “tr” tag down so it become invisible.

```
So I need both “tr” tags become visible and the first one have scroll bar to get the expanded data.

scrollTV class as the following
div.scrollTV {
height:100%;
width:99%;
border:0px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle with a example showing your problem. This makes it easier for people to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting height in percentage format as "100%", try to set in "px" format. It should solve the problem.

```
div.scrollTV { //set height in "px" format instead of "%"
height:100px;
width:99%;
border:0px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

(OR)

If using percentage format, it defines the height in percent of the containing block i.e., "td" - You need to set the height of "td" in "px" format.

```
td.scrollTV_TD { //set height of td in "px" format
height:100px;
}
```